# Running CATIA script from Microsoft VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, catia

I am currently developing a macro for CATIA software. While the CATIA itself has a visual basic editor, but I am writing my code in the VSCode editor.

When I want to run my macro, I should go to the folder containing the code, and double click the code, and since the CATSctript file extension is assigned to CATIA, it will be executed in CATIA.

Is there any way that I can run the code (an action like double clicking in windows explorer) right from the VSCode? For example, I press the F5 and the code will be executed in CATIA.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed an extension, asign CATScript as vbs language, right mouse button click and here it is.

[image]